# Imagen thymeleaf error 500

Tags: imagen, variables, foreach, thymeleaf

Tengo un problema, intento enviar la direccion de una imagen por una variable en un for each en el html pero me da `error 500` y `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'post' cannot be found on object of type 'com.tazaflor.model.Post' - maybe not public or not valid?`

esa es la imagen que quiero colocar, la Spring-1.jpg

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo error en la linea donde esta la etiqueta `<img>` con el `th:src="${post.urlImg}"`

```
    <div class="container">
            <!--cards-->
            <div  class="row">
                <div th:each ="post:${posts}" class="col-3 ">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<!-- en esta linea me da error --><img class="card-img-top" th:src="${post.urlImg}"  src="../static/img/Spring-1.jpg"  alt="Card image"/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 th:text="${post.titulo}" class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p th:text="${post.description}" class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the
                                card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a th:href="@{/home/post?id=}+${post.id}" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Aca es donde llamo el get y mando la lista de objetos

```
@GetMapping(path = "/public")
public ModelAndView post() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView(Paginas.HOME);
    modelAndView.addObject("posts", this.getPost());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Y este es mi post y ahi tengo la direccion, y me funciona usar ese url

```
public class Post {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String urlImg="http://localhost:8080/img/Spring-1.jpg";
    private Date fecha;
    private String titulo;

    public Post(int id, String description, String uriImg, Date fecha, String titulo) {

        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.urlImg = uriImg;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
```

Cuando quito la etiqueta de imagen en el html me funciona bien el for each pero falla con el post.urlImg

alguna sugerencia, debo usar algun bean o algo asi,

Comment: No es de mucha ayuda, pero el error indica que tu problema podria venir de `th:each="post: ${posts}"`. Por alguna razon no crea la variable `post` al iterar `posts`. Solo se me ocurre que haya algun problema con el HTML, y la tag de imagen resulte afuera de la iteracion de `posts`.

Comment: pero es que cuando quito esta linea lo demas funciona bien   <img class="card-img-top" th:src="${post.urlImg}"  src="../static/img/Spring-1.jpg"  alt="Card image"/>

Comment: tal caso es ese el problema que debo hacer?

Comment: Podrias compartir los metodos que afecten a la variable `getUrlImg` en tu clase `Post`? Existe getter para ella?